# UISearchcontroller is not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have implemented the search functionality as below. I am able to retrieve the rows based on search string but they are empty, when i click on the empty search result cell am able to navigate correctly for each search result.I am using story board configured cells to display the table. I mean am using tags in order to populate the data and the images.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    sqlDatabase = [SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance];           
    filteredItemist=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[sqlDatabase fetchCropListBySoilName:soilName]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    // Configure the cell...

     Crop * crop = [filteredItemist objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",crop.cropName.lowercaseString];

    UIImageView *cropImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    cropImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:str];

    UILabel *cropNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:70];
    cropNameLabel.text = [crop cropName];

    return cell;

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationItem.title = @"Item List";
    filteredItemist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[sqlDatabase fetchCropListBySoilName:soilName]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    if([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
        [filteredItemist removeAllObjects];
        [filteredItemist addObjectsFromArray:[sqlDatabase fetchCropListBySoilName:soilName]];

    }
    else{
        isFiltered = TRUE;
        [filteredItemist removeAllObjects];
        for(Crop *i in [sqlDatabase fetchCropListBySoilName:soilName]){
            NSRange stringRange = [[i cropName]rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(stringRange.location !=NSNotFound){
                [filteredItemist addObject:i];
            }
        }

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];

    return YES;
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

[image]

Edit :

after changing the code to self.tableview :

[image]

Comment: Log your `Crop` object.

Comment: these are the attributes in  NSInteger cropId;
    NSString* cropName;
    NSInteger farmId;
    NSInteger Soil_id;  and in the search results the object has the data but somehow am not able to populate the lables from the story board upon table reload.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

use this :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Search results displayed in a separate table view. So if you use `tableView` without self you may be referring search results table view.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting the data now . But the cell size is not what i get in my initial view or what I defined in the story board its much smaller size and hence its splitting my single cell in to two cells in the resultant table.I have added the image as Edit in my post . Pls check . Thank you

Comment: Edit your heightForRowAtIndexPath method to reflect the height change.